# Alternate way of TCP/ IP communication protocal

Tags: tcp, ip, protocols, communication

Alternate way of TCP/ IP communication protocal.

I am using TCP/ IP communication protocol to connect device and communicating with one device to another.
But sometime ping is not reliable especially in firewalls environments.
Let me know the any another way to find out the connection status of the connected devices.

Comment: I need to check if I am able to connect to multiple devices consistently.
Currently, I try to ping the devices, and if I receive a reply back, I say I am connected.
But there can be cases where the ping is disabled, or there are some firewall rules due to which I cannot ping the device.
In such cases I cannot rely o the ping.
Is there any other way through which I could check my connectivity with the devices, without pinging them.
I am using TCP/IP protocol for communication.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with it is not reliable in firewall environments? Do you get a timeout on your ping-request or what? Then something is wrong with your routing on your firewall.

To your question: There's actually just the way over dns () so if there's a DNS in your network you should be able to ping with his net-name. But there's really no difference between this and an IP. You can't ping a MAC-Address (Layer 2).

Now the question, whats the point of this question (Any errors?)

Comment: I think, he wants to do a ping without control over that firewall.

Comment: Then he needs a direct connection to this device or an another router, how knows the route to the other device an doesn't need to send the request to the firewall. What do you think?

Comment: I think he is looking for a protocol that bypasses security mechanisms to get the online status of a device in any network area. I hope, there´s no solution for this.

Comment: Ah, this way "reliable especially in firewalls environments" makes sense =D

Comment: I need to check if I am able to connect to multiple devices consistently.
Currently, I try to ping the devices, and if I receive a reply back, I say I am connected.
But there can be cases where the ping is disabled, or there are some firewall rules due to which I cannot ping the device.
In such cases I cannot rely o the ping.
Is there any other way through which I could check my connectivity with the devices, without pinging them.
I am using TCP/IP protocol for communication.